# Command to run an application with Administrator privileges, but NOT AS administrator (prompt with UAC)

Tags: windows-7, batch, uac

I want to start Notepad with elevated privileges to edit C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host. Notmally I would type *notepad* in the search box, and with the program highlighted hot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, click Yes on the UAC prompt and then open the file. I do this often, so I want a batch file to do it.

I tried the following command:

```
runas /user:Administrator /savecred notepad.exe path\to\file
```

But this is not exactly what I want, as it prompts for the password of the Administrator account. I really want a command to start a program with elevated privileges for the current user account.

I run Windows 7 RC.

Comment: Note for others seeing this: the correct way to elevate as your own user from a CLI is through PowerShell (or VBScript): `Start-Process -Verb runas notepad.exe` or from cmd with shorthand `powershell -c start -verb runas notepad.exe`. PowerShell's `-Verb runas` does not require switching users as the standalone `runas` command does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Notepad is a Windows tool, you may not set "Run always as administrator", but there's a trick. Create a symbolic link and open the properties dialog. Under the link properties, select Advanced (bottom right button) and select "Run link as administrator". This should elevate the process.

I hope this is still the same on Windows 7 (I tested on Windows Vista).

Comment: Perhaps you could include the directions to create a symbolic link? I don't think it's something most users would ever find. :)

Comment: I created the symbolic link using mklink. The advanced button is disabled. I turned of UAC instead :p

Comment: The Advanced button on the Shortcut tab is indeed disabled on my Win7 installation (I'm running 7 Pro x64).  
However, on the Compatibility tab, there is an option to "Run this program as an administrator" ... so it looks as though things just got moved around between Vista and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a shortcut to Notepad, and then going to its properties => Advanced run as administrator works on Windows 7 64 bit.

This is a good solution for me. I was looking for a way to add lines to the `hosts` file. This is not ideal, but it saves me a lot of time finding the damn thing.

Comment: It is usually at C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts